# Why is the pandasql query returning max value when i didnt specify it to return

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas, pandasql

```
import pandas as pd
from  pandasql import sqldf
pysqldf=lambda query:sqldf(query=query,env=globals())
df=pd.read_csv('https://s3.amazonaws.com/content.udacity-data.com/courses/ud359/weather_underground.csv')
query="SELECT fog,maxtempi from df GROUP BY fog"

print(pysqldf(query))
```

output

```
   fog      maxtempi
0    0        86
1    1        81
```

In this I understood the table is getting grouped by is group fog into 2 categories but I didn't understand why maxtempi are getting those values as I didn't explicitly specify to return the max temperature.

Comment: "i didn't explicitly specify to return the max temperature" - but what's this: `SELECT fog,maxtempi ...`?

Comment: maxtempi is the column name.

Comment: maxtempi is the max temperature of that day

Comment: And the table has 30 entries but why did it pick the max value from the set of all max values